# integration-jms:outbound-gateway - SpEL destination queue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using an `integration-jms:outbound-gateway` where `xmlns:integration-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"`

Looking at the xsd (http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd) I can't see anything that will allow me to use a SpEL expression for the destination queue.

Anyone got an ideas on how I could do this as I need to be able to specify the queue name at runtime via a header in my gateway:

```
pulbic interface MyGateway {
    String request(@Header("queueName") String queueName, String requestMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look into very old version.

With current (4.0) release you can do this:

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway request-channel="myChannel"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        request-destination-expression="headers.queueName"/>
```

Actually modern IDE can resolve actual XSD from jars on classpath, when you configure them for your application: from Maven, Gradle or even manually.

It isn't clear why you try to use the Internet resource

Comment: Unfortunately, for historic reasons, the unversioned internet schemas have to stay at v1.0 to avoid breaking old applications. Look at the versioned schemas (`...4.0.xsd`), or look at the current versions in github.